# How to set active row in UltrDropdown using a value in a particular row

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a Ultradropdown in which I have to set the row in select as default. I have a value of the row through which can I make the row selected?

//Code

```
 Dim workflowId = 256
 cboWorkflows.ActiveRow = ???
```

In the above code the dropdown has a column in which one of them contains the value 256. so using that I should now make the row selected in dropdown.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are aware of the column name you could do it like the following:

```
   For Each row As UltraGridRow In UltraDropDown1.Rows()
        If row.Cells("YouDesiredColumnNameHere").Value = 256 Then
            row.Activate()
        End If
    Next
```

If this is not helpful, please provide me more details about the usage of the UltraDropDown in your application.

Comment: I don't want to loop through all the rows, since my grid has more numbers.

Comment: The Rows collection also has a GetRowWithListIndex method that can be used to get a specific row if you know the index or have a reference to the list item rather than looping through the rows: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection~GetRowWithListIndex(Int32).html